# itemprop=url property on picture element not validating

Tags: html, image, url, schema.org, microdata

I have the code below which if I test it on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool, I get an error

> A value for the `url` field is required.

on the image element.

I tried placing the `itemprop='url'` attribute on the `picture`, `source` and `img` element but the error remains the same. How can I add the `url` property so Google accepts the structured data?

```html
<li itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/LocalBusiness'>
<div>
    <div itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/venues/220/studio-54">
        <picture>
            <source itemprop='url' type='image/webp' data-srcset='/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.webp'>
            <img data-src="/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.jpg"/>
        </picture>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href='http://www.example.com/venues/220/studio-54'>
        <span itemprop="name">Studio-54</span></a></h3>
        <div itemprop='address' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/PostalAddress'>
        <a itemprop='addressLocality' href="http://www.example.com/vendors/venues/c/netherlands/north-holland/amsterdam">Amsterdam</a>, <span itemprop='addressRegion'>North-Holland</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#values) section in the Microdata spec (Working Draft):

- When adding the `itemprop` attribute to an `img` or `source` element, Microdata uses the value of the `src` attribute.
- When adding the `itemprop` attribute to a `picture` element, Microdata uses the textContent of the element.

In your case, you might want to add a `src` attribute to the `img` element (which is required by HTML anyway, in addition to the `alt` attribute), and move the `itemprop` from `source` (which requires a `srcset` attribute) to `img`:

```html
<img itemprop="url" src="/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.jpg" data-src="/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.jpg" alt="" />
```

If you want to keep the attributes like that (e.g., for lazy loading), you could use a `link` element to provide the URL of the image (browsers don’t load this):

```html
<div itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>

  <a href='http://www.example.com/venues/220/studio-54'>
    <picture>
      <source type='image/webp' data-srcset='/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.webp'>
      <img data-src='/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.jpg' />
    </picture>
  </a>

  <link itemprop='url' href='/images/venues/medium/220_663_studio-54.webp' />

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The reason I have no `src` attribute on the image, is because I use lazy loading for better page performance and that attribute is added and populated when the image element comes into the browser viewport. With your proposed solution it seems I have to forfeit the lazy loading thereby drastically reducing my page performance. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @Flo: I added an alternative to my answer. If you can’t use `link`, then yes, you either have to stop using lazy loading, or you have to accept that your structured data can only be read by Microdata consumers that execute JavaScript.